# Detox: How to tap on iOS push notification in notification centre using detox

Tags: ios, detox

I am new to detox and mobile automation. I want to tap on iOS push notification in notification centre using detox.
OR is there any other tool I can use with detox in order to tap on notification on iOS ?

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: did you ever resolve this? The suggestions below don't seem to address the issue. The permissions allow the notification to appear, but I want to programmatically tap it when it does appear.

Answer (score 5):

In your `init.js` configuration file you can add:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
  await detox.init(config, { launchApp: false });
  await device.launchApp({newInstance: true, permissions: {notifications: 'YES'}});
});
```

Also you can check the example on the Documentation:
https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/detox/test/e2e/13.permissions.test.js

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for a way to specify the permissions before the app was launched, but it wasn't clear how. This helped.

Answer (score 2):

base on Detox document, permission is integrated when you call launchApp.
You can set permission to deny Notification Alert instead of trying to tap on that.

```
device.launchApp({ newInstance: true, permissions: { notifications: 'NO' } });
```